# In C++ how would I go about getting a specific line from a text file and storing that in a char vector?

Tags: c++, vector, char, getline

I want to have my program open a text file, go down to a specific line (for example, line 18) and store each character on that line in a char vector.

I'm fairly new to programming in general so this may not be the best way but here's what I plan on doing:

1) Get specific line and store it in a string

2) Convert that string to a char vector. I'm using a vector instead of an array so I can use pushback() to make the vector the exact size needed instead of allocating too much or too little in an array.

I can do step 2 just fine but it is step 1 I'm having trouble with. How do I make it go to a specific line?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Show us your code?

Answer (score 2):

Just read all lines and ignore those you are not interested in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
        std::ifstream file("file.ext");
        std::string line;
        unsigned int line_number(1);
        const unsigned int requested_line_number(4);
        while (std::getline(file, line))
        {
                if (line_number == requested_line_number)
                {
                        std::cout << line << "\n";
                }
                line_number++;
        }
}
```

This code is of course devoid of error handling, and naturally, you wouldn't want to hardcode your line number most of the time, but you get the idea.

Also, I don't really see what the char vector / array is for. Use `std::string` for your string handling needs, that's what it's made for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code; I think I can use it. I am converting the string to a vector because what I need to do with the line is send keystrokes to another window, which I don't think can be done (at least not very easily) with a string.

Comment: @Jim: Do `std::vector<char> charvec(line.begin(), line.end());`  to convert string to vector.

Comment: @Jim: what specific problem do you have with a string compared to a vector? I don't think there's anything you can do with a vector that you can't do with a string.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I need to send individual keystrokes for each character in the string. That's why I am converting it to a vector.

Comment: You can iterate through a string in just the same way as a vector: `for (std::string::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {send_keystroke(*i);}`. There's no need to convert to a vector to do that. (By the way, this should have been a comment, not an answer.)